# How do I setup VNC (remote desktop) on CentOS 6?

Tags: linux, centos, remote-access, vnc

After screwing around with command line and getting nowhere, I will follow this question with an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
yum install tigervnc-server
chkconfig --add vncserver
[edit /etc/sysconfig/vncservers to liking]
service vncserver start
yum install tigervnc
vncviewer localhost
```

Comment: +1 but would add an update to the iptables to open up the port described in /etc/sysconfig/vncservers (say 5902 if uncommenting the default :2 setting).

Answer (score 0):

1. Applications -> System Tools -> Terminal
2. Type: su
3. Type: yum install vino
4. System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop
5. Check: Allow other users to view your desktop
6. [Optional] Uncheck: You must confirm each access to this machine
7. [Optional] Check: Require the user to enter this password: [enter password]
8. System -> Administration -> Firewall
9. Other Ports -> Add
10. Check: user Defined
11. Port / Port Range: 5900
12. Click OK
13. Click Apply
14. Use a VNC viewer to connect (e.g. RealVNC on Windows)